# Pegar registros com data maior que a atual - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-5

Preciso listar os agendamentos que tem data maior ou igual a data atual, estou fazendo da forma abaixo mas não funciona, ele não retorna nenhum registro.

```
Auth::user()->Agendamentos->where('data', '>=', date("Y-m-d h:i:s"))
```

Estou fazendo isso na minha `view`. Se eu tiro esse `where` funciona normalmente, porém ele lista tudo, tanto os com data passada quanto os com data futura.

Meu campo *data* armazena os dados no formato `datetime` (2017-07-01 10:25:45).

Comment: O seu campo no banco é um `DateTime` realmente, tem como colocar o layout da sua tabela?, porque vendo assim, parece correto @RayLan

Comment: Sim, isso está certo. $table->dateTime('data');

Comment: Olha só tem uma resposta, mas, basicamente se você fizer isso ou utilizar igual está na sua resposta tem que funcionar do mesmo jeito talvez você precise testar assim` `Auth::user()->Agendamentos->where('data', '>=', date("Y-m-d"))` e ai me fala qual resultado aparentemente deu, ou seja, sem hora, minutos e segundos somente a data?

Comment: também não funciona. Estranho que a query no phpmyadmin funciona de forma correta. SELECT * FROM `agendamentos` WHERE data >= '2017-06-01 11:29:57' AND `medico_id` = 1

Comment: Usa assim: `Auth::user()->Agendamentos()->where('data', '>=', date("Y-m-d h:i:s"))->get()` e fala a pra mim o que deu? Ou seja em vez da lista, vai utilize o where no método!

Comment: Mudei o tipo do campo para date e comparei usando só o date("Y-m-d"), mas nem assim funciona

Comment: Acho que vou pegar isso no controller com um raw...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59692/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-raylan-soares).

Comment: como está seu código no controller?

Comment: Não tem nada relacionado a isso no controller, estou pegando pelo relacionamento através do usuário logado. Tudo acontece na view com o Auth::user()->Agendamentos

Comment: está muito confuso! e me parece errado também de um certo modo, falta contexto por isso da grande duvida, bom quem sabe você colocando mais detalhes ...

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente garanta que suas datas sejam tratadas corretamente no formato global que utiliza Carbon: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators ...

```
class SeuModelo {

    protected $dates = [
        'data',
    ];
    ...
```

O filtro do where você pode utilizar o Carbon:

```
Auth::user()->Agendamentos->where('data', '>=', \Carbon::now())
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, tratei o Model e usei o Carbon, mas ainda sim não funciona. Imprimi os 2 resultados, o campo data e o carbon estão no mesmo formato, não sei qual o problema. Obs: Estou com laravel 5.1

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta o resultado da query com e sem o uso do where?